# I am looking for Graph API url to retrive Site usage (/_layouts/15/siteanalytics.aspx) for a single sharepoint online site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api

I am looking for Graph API url to retrive Site usage (/_layouts/15/siteanalytics.aspx) for a single sharepoint online  site collection .

Answer (score 1):

please have a look here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0

although it doesn't give you a single site collection, you can parse the resulting csv to get what you need.

you can also try 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/itemanalytics-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
this one lets you specify the specific site, but gives you not very much information.

Hopefully that helps.